# How to specify in a bat file that a script needs to be called in Cygwin mode?

Tags: perl, shell, cygwin, windows-server-2003, cmd

I wrote a perl script which uses some linux commands (`grep`, `ls` etc..). I can successfully run this from Cygwin or Linux. I want this task to be run periodically on a Windows Server which has Cygwin installed. I was planning to use Windows task scheduler. But I am not sure how to specify in a Windows bat file, that my perl script needs to be called in Cygwin mode?

EDIT: I tried the command by Glenn. When I tried running the perl script, it doesn't seem to respond. So I tried with a sample script: `test.sh`, which has the following two lines:

```
ls -l
cd ..
```

Here is the screen capture of what I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a great fan of cygwin and personally prefer natively compiled versions of the GNU tools, e.g. [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).

I also wonder why you would be using `grep`, `ls` etc. from a Perl script. Most of that functionality can be handled natively by Perl and this usually results in much better portability and robustness.

Comment: @David I just started with Perl and not aware of API. So I was just trying to port a similar Unix script to Windows. I will have a look at the API for sure.

Comment: @Ravi When I first started with Perl on Windows I used `system` a lot to invoke the standard GNU tools. This mostly worked, but would often produce rather odd results. For example some routines resulted in files created with invalid owners which then could not be deleted. If you are calling `grep` you could likely do it with a plain Perl regexp. As for `ls` then that might be a `glob` or somesuch.

Comment: @David: Thanks a bunch, David. Will give them a try!

Comment: `ls` can be written in Perl with `opendir; readdir; closedir`, and `stat` if you're parsing the ls output.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps (untested):  `c:\cygwin\bash.exe -c /path/to/your/script.pl`

UPDATE:

The last error message reveals one problem:  your script is a DOS format file (CRLF line endings), while cygwin looks for UNIX format (LF line endings).  The stray carriage returns at the end of each line is the problem. For example, there's no directory named "..\r"

Use a text editor where you can specify the line endings to use.  In a bash shell, you can do `dos2unix test.sh`

The `ls` error indicates that /bin and /usr/bin are not in your bash environment's $PATH -- is that true?

Comment: or `C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c /usr/bin/perl /path/to/script.pl`

Comment: Updated the question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I fixed line ending problem but still "command not found" is happening. BTW I do have /usr/bin in my path variable!

Answer (score 1):

Just add cygwin to your path before running perl. For example, I often run `find` in a dos shell, but get the rather horrible message *FIND: Parameter format not correct*. Bah! Instead I have to run `find` via a dos cmd file `cyg.cmd`:

```
c:> find . -iname interesting.txt
FIND: Parameter format not correct
c:> cyg find . -iname interesting.txt
sub/sub/interesting.TXT
c:> type bin\cyg.cmd
setlocal
PATH=c:\Progs\Cygwin\bin;%PATH%
%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
endlocal
```

The important bit here is the `PATH=c:\Progs\Cygwin\bin;%PATH%`.

BTW, I much prefer the cygwin versions of the tools rather than their MinGW equivalents—the environment is much closer to Mac/Linux, and portability is important after all.

Answer (score 1):

You run cygwin bash, but you still have to setup your PATH. Unless you set it in your profile, but initialize the profile then with `bash -i`.

1. Either specify the full path to cygwin commands needed, like `/bin/ls`, `/bin/grep`,
2. or add `c:\cygwin\bin` and maybe other paths to your `PATH` beforehand.

2nd preferred. Like

```
schedule.bat:
PATH=C:\cygwin\bin;%PATH%
sh -c ./schedule.sh

schedule.sh:
#!/bin/sh
ls ...
grep ...
perl ...
```

schedule.sh gets the environment with the PATH from the parent process `sh.exe`, which inherits it from your bat. 
Seperating shell scripts from batch files just for easier testing. You can call most cygwin programs from cmd.exe also.

You cannot set `/usr/bin` in your DOS `PATH`, DOS will not have a `c:/usr` directory. And it only works if you are in `C:`